# URL Rewriting if it is a single post / redirecting post - post type

Tags: posts, url-rewriting

I have a unique kind of question that I've been wrapping my brain around. Google is penalizing us with duplicate content because you can access our single blog posts both by going to:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/the-post-slug
```

as well as :

```
http://www.domain.com/the-post-slug
```

The option we really want is:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/the-post-slug
```

and if a user or googlebot happens to goto:

```
http://www.domain.com/the-post-slug
```

redirect them to:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/the-post-slug
```

I know this is a particular situation, but we have many custom post types in our system. 
So our structure looks like this.

```
http://www.domain.com/food/pizza
http://www.domain.com/ice-cream/strawberry
http://www.domain.com/fireworks/bottle-rockets
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is find some kind of filter that logically checks if the post_type is post and redirect:

```
http://www.domain.com/the-post-slug
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/post-slug
```

I tried modifying the register_post_type for the post object, and adding with_front => false and adding blog to the slug, but that doesn't work.

I was able to add /blog/%postname%/ to the permalink structure, and I was successfully able to have a decent structure going that was working, but I got stuck on the taxonomies. When I went to a taxonomy page, I had to goto:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/the-taxonomy/flavors
```

and:

```
http://www.domain.com/the-taxonomy/flavors
```

was giving me a 404. So even if I can find a way to make the taxonomies work to where I can do:

```
http://www.domain.com/the-taxonomy/flavors
```

that would be awesome! As another side note, I also added with_front to the register_taxonomy, but that was not doing anything either. I even hard flushed the rewrites on all the changes I did.

I know this is a lot, but my brain cannot go any further.. lol

TIA!

Any insight on this?

Comment: `'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false )` is your answer, add your taxonomy registration code to your question if it's not working for you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all set your permalink structure to `/%postname%`.

After that add a rewrite rule to rewrite all request like `example.com/blog/postname` to the appropriate query:

```
add_action('init', 'blog_front');

function blog_front() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^blog/([^/]+)/?','index.php?name=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Now you have to prevent the duplicate url, sending a 301 redirect when `example.com/postname` is requested:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'say_hello_to_google');

function say_hello_to_google() {
  if ( is_main_query() && is_single() && ( empty( get_post_type() ) || (get_post_type() === 'post') ) ) {
    if ( strpos( trim( add_query_arg( array() ), '/' ), 'blog' ) !== 0 ) {
      global $post;
      $url = str_replace( $post->post_name, 'blog/' . $post->post_name, get_permalink( $post ) );
      wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
      exit(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Finally you have to create permalink for your post with 'blog/' in front:

```
add_filter('the_permalink', 'post_permalink_w_blog');

function post_permalink_w_blog( $link ) {
  global $post;
  if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
    $link = str_replace( $post->post_name, 'blog/' . $post->post_name, get_permalink( $post ) );
  }
  return $link; 
}
```

Last thing to is **flush rewrite rules** and... test.

---

### Edit

As **@Milo** pointed out in comments, all of this can be avoided by setting  permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%` and then use the param `'rewrite'` having `'with_front'` to `false` for **all** CPTs and **all** taxonomies.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false )
```

The problem is that most times, in a average WP install with a lot of CPT and taxonomies, there are chances that some of them are registred via 3rd party plugins...
in that case if that plugins register the CPTs/taxonomies not using `'with_front' => false` it's a problem and the solution posted above is the last chance.

In addiction I have to say that standard categories and tags are registered with 'with_front' = true, so using this alternative method also standard category and tag must be re-registered with `with_front` param setted to `false`.

Comment: none of this is necessary if the permalink structure is `/blog/%postname%/` and taxonomies are correctly registered to not use the `/blog/` front. I think the issue is that OP just didn't register the taxonomies with the correct arguments.

Comment: same for CPTs, register them with `'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false )` and they won't be prepended with `/blog/`

Comment: @Milo updated answer.

Comment: I tried the quick fix of just adding with_front to the register_taxonomy, and changed the permalink structure to /blog/%postname%/ and when I go to http://www.domain.com/work-type/graphic-design I get a 404, and if I goto  http://www.domain.com/blog/work-type/graphic-design I also get a 404 error. What I did before to register the taxonomies was use the Custom Post Type plugin. I then generated the code from the plugin, put it in my functions.php and deleted the taxonomy from the plugin, basically it's only getting registered with the functions.php. Here is my tax: http://pastebin.com/MSydZbZN

Comment: @AaronOlieOlin your code contains an error: `'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false)` is inside `'labels'` array. Try [this](http://pastebin.com/1GViC7nM) and flush rewrite rules. Also remember that you have to re-register standard category and standard tags if you don't want `'/blog'` in front of them.

Comment: Aw man... how amateur is that! It's working perfectly now! I appreciate everyone's fresh eyes and solutions to this! You guys are awesome. Thanks again Milo, and G.M.!